# Where can I find free WMA Conversion Software?

Tags: iphone, itunes, software-recommendation

I have a huge collection of WMA files (from my Zune days). And of course, my iPhones can't do anything with them. Does anyone know of TRULY free (preferably open-source) WMA conversion software? Is that even legal? If it exists, someone please let me know where to find it. I've been searching, and only came up with AVS Audio Converter...which is "free..." They give you a free trial, but each encode has a voice logo over your file. I could just use Audacity to edit that out, but who wants to go through that?

Anyway, please let me know if free WMA conversion software exists anywhere on this world wide internetz.

Comment: Are these files protected by DRM?

Comment: Nope. No copyright protection.

Comment: Should this go on superuser instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running Windows the free version of [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) will do this:

> Record CDs and convert MP3s, M4A, OGG, FLAC and WMA files etc. into other formats.

It comes with a time limited mp3 encoder, but you can replace that yourself. However, this probably isn't an issue if you're converting for the iPhone.

Comment: It also converts whole folders of files in one go, and you don't have to add the files to it's library for this to work either.

Answer (score 9):

If these are unprotected files (non-DRM), you should be able to drop them directly into iTunes on a Mac and convert them to MP3 or AAC. I've never owned or used a Windows PC so I don't know if the same thing will work on Windows iTunes, but you could give it a try.

On a Mac, you can also install Flip4Mac, which enables you to load WMA files in QuickTime and convert them to MP3 or AAC. If you have a bunch of files, you could set up an Autmomator action to automatically do this on a folder full of files.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know iTunes did WMA conversion. I have a MacBook, but I'm on my Windows laptop at work, which doesn't have iTunes. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can do all that. As far as I can tell, it's a commandline-only program, but that has the plus side that you can run it in batch mode easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iTunes for Windows, it is easy.

Launch iTunes, and then click `File > Add File to Library` to open WMA files that you want to import. Then a window will pop up as clearly shown in the picture below. Just click `Convert` to convert WMA to iTunes M4A format. Once the conversion is done, you can play WMA files in iTunes or import WMA to iPhone, iPad and iPod.

[image]

But if you are using iTunes for Mac, it is a little complicate. You'd better to convert WMA to iPhone supported formats. Maybe [this step by step guide](http://www.faasoft.com/articles/wma-to-itunes-to-play-wma-on-iphone-ipad-ipod.html) will help you.

If your WMA files are DRM-protected, you have to remove the DRM first.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows version of iTunes already does conversion of non-protected wma files, so you could just use iTunes to re-encode your eligible files.